# Animating page contents in and out of window based on their position in navigation. [Fiddle inside]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently trying to implement a "flow" to my site. What I am trying to achieve is to animate in and out the page content based on buttons clicked in the navigation menu. The navigation menu is the only consistent element. The menu has 3 buttons Phone, Home and Mail. At the moment the starting content is that of the Phone page, but eventually I'd need to switch it to Home. Now the goal is to animate the content container of the current "page" out and the content of the "page" whos navigation button has been clicked in.

The tricky part is this. When I start on Phone page and click on Home button the Phone page container slides away to left and Home content comes in from right. This is the desired effect as Phone is to the left of Home. This also work appropriately when going from Home to Mail. But when I want to move from say Mail to Home I need the content of phone to slide away to right and the content of Home to come in from left. Also when going from 1 far end to the opposite I want to slide past the content between.

**UPDATE 2**

So the fix to "I do not know what is causing this" was to simply move this line `currBoxX = destBoxX;` out of the comparing to after it. I was dumb enough to miss that. I have achieved almost the functionality I wanted, but I still don't know how to display the inbetween contents when going from one page over some inbetween to other one. This don't matter anymore as Rick Hitchock has shown me how this whole thing can be done much more effectively. So check out his answer if you're curious.

**----**

Now it kind of works on the first run and also only if I go from one menu button to the very next.
The problem is that in second round it falls starts moving the containers from wrong place and **I do not know what is causing this**. *To see this in work go to the fiddle and first click on Home then Mail then Home again, then Phone. Till now it was exactly how I want it. Now click on Home and it will come in from wrong side. Any ideas?*

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ykbgT/8256/)

What I have done was storing a value of current content container and comparing it to value of destination container. The container value starts at 1 for the leftmost and highest is 3 for the rightmost. So when I go from Phone (1) to Home (2) the destination value is higher than current so I know the button is to the right of the original on and I call the slide left animation..

*Calling functions with value of current container in argument*

```
<div class="nav_btn" onclick="goToBox(1,'#phone_box')">
            Phone</div>
        <div class="nav_btn" onclick="goToBox(2,'#home_box')">
            Home</div>
        <div class="nav_btn" onclick="goToBox(3,'#mail_box')">
            Mail</div>
```

*comparing value of current and destination container*

```
if (destBoxX > currBoxX) {
        currBoxX = destBoxX;
        slideLeft();
    } 
    else {
        slideRight();
    }
```

**End of update**

I am not that skilled and I am really trying my best here, but I am getting really lost in the animations. I know the problem is in me animating everything through the property of left, but I unfortunately have no clue how to approach this to get to the desired functionality.

Therefore I'd like to hear any tips/advices on how it could be done. Also, do you even think I can do this with a simple and general function like the current one or is what I want too complex and should I maybe just create more functions?

Looking forward to your replies.

[current JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ykbgT/8251/)

*Here's the function*

```
function goToBox(boxid){
    $(".currentBox").animate({
        left: '-50%'
    }, 500, function() {
        $(".currentBox").css('left', '150%');
        $(".currentBox").appendTo('#container');     
    });
    $(".currentBox").removeClass("currentBox");
    $(boxid).addClass( "currentBox" );
    $(boxid).animate({
        left: '50%'
    }, 500);  
};
```

*and this is how I call it*

```
<nav>
    <div id="naw_wrap">
        <div class="nav_btn" onclick="goToBox('#phone_box')">Phone</div>
        <div class="nav_btn" onclick="goToBox('#home_box')">Home</div>
        <div class="nav_btn" onclick="goToBox('#mail_box')">Mail</div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I just finished a project like this. Your best option is to use css classes to animate the pages. Add and remove the classes using javascript. To more appropriately answer your question, if you make your animations into classes, you can then reverse the it to make the sliding effect come from the other direction.

Comment: allright. I've made some progress in those 20 mins. I think I am onto something. If you're interested check back in like an hour I'll do my best to update this by then. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of keeping track of the selected box, you can scroll directly to it, like this:

```
function goToBox(boxid){
  $('body').animate({
    scrollLeft: $(boxid).offset().left
  }, 500);
};
```

You'll need to make some changes to your CSS.

This removes scrollbars from the window:

```
body {
  ...
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

You have 3 boxes, all of which are 100% wide.  So your container should be 300% wide.  Since `overflow: hidden` has been added to the body, it's no longer needed on the container:

```
#container {
  ...
  width: 300%;
}
```

Your boxes are 1/3 the width of `container`, so they need 1/3 width.  They no longer need absolute positioning, and `float: left` causes them to appear side-by-side:

```
.box {
  ...
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

Finally, `naw_wrap` needs fixed positioning, so it stays visible while the body scrolls:

```
#naw_wrap{
  ...
  position: fixed;
}
```

### Fiddle

Comment: Oh. My. God. I love you dude, you just wiped the floor with my brain. Solving it so simply I love it. I am gonna update my previous update with the result I got now, which is the correct animation all the time but when it goes over one "page" it just skips it and not shows it like your does which is what I wanted as well. So I will be accepting your answer right after I do that. Thank you!